# Python assignment for school

Tags: python

```
import random

number= random.randint(1,10)
count=0
guess=""
guess=int(input("please guess:")
while guess!= number:
    if guess < number:
          print("lower")
          count++
    elif guess > number:
          print("higher")
          count++
elif guess==number:
print("Good job, you got my number")
print("You got it in,",count,"tries")
```

FOr some reason when i try to run it, it says I have invalid syntax. Please help.

Comment: Your indentation is wrong on the last two lines and `count++` isn't valid Python. You're also missing a closing parenthesis on line 6.

Comment: Blender is right on all counts :)

Comment: I want to let you know the reason this was downvoted is that you didn't specify what the syntax errors were. In this case it was pretty clear, but sometimes it's not obvious, and it's best to help the people helping you by directing them to the problem.

Answer (score 3):

This is Python, not C or JS. This:

```
count++
```

Should be written as:

```
count += 1
```

Also, your keep in mind that Python is indentation-sensitive.

```
while guess!= number:
    if guess < number:
        print("lower")
        count++
    elif guess > number:
        print("higher")
        count++
    elif guess==number:
        print("Good job, you got my number")
        print("You got it in,",count,"tries")
```

And lastly, you're missing a closing parenthesis:

```
guess=int(input("please guess:"))
```

Well, good luck learning!

Answer (score 2):

You're missing an end parenthesis

```
guess=int(input("please guess:")
```

Should be:

```
guess=int(input("please guess:"))
```

Hope that helps

You also need to change your indenting on this:

```
elif guess==number:
    print("Good job, you got my number")
    print("You got it in,",count,"tries")
```

Also do increment correctly